# Sum of numbers equally divisible by items in an array (remainder) - nested for loops

Tags: javascript

So I found this problem in the conclusion of this article: 
https://medium.com/@popflorin1705/javascript-coding-challenge-1-6d9c712963d2

What I am trying to do is sum all the numbers that are equally divisible by each item in the provided array. In my code, I want to sum all the numbers divisible by 5, 10, 12, etc. from 0 to whatever number I specify (sumOfMultiples(x) when called).

Also, in some cases I have been able to get the correct answer when there is only one item in the array, but adding additional items to the array results in sum = 0. Why does this happen?

I am new to programming, so if your solutions could maybe stick to nested for loops or .forEach, that would make more sense to me. Not just looking for a solution, but I want to understand how this problem should be structured/ what I am missing.

The code I provided has been the closest to what I think works, so going off that would make the most logical sense to me.

Thanks in advance!

```
function sumOfMultiples(number) {
    let numb = [5, 10, 12];
    let sum = 0;
    for (let x=0; x<=numb.length; x++){
        for (let i=0; i<number; i++) {
            if(i % numb === 0){
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }        
}
```

Comment: are you trying to get the sum of all numbers divisible by 5, 10 and 12 as separated sums (3 numbers in this case) or as 1 sum (1 number)?

Comment: I think you're returning the sum too early. You should place the `return` statement after the body of two for loops. In your case, the return is simulating a `break;` for the outer for loop

Comment: No, I was trying just to sum all those numbers that are divisible by the numbers in the array. I hadn't really thought of what to do if a number was divisible by multiple numbers from the array (whether to add them multiple times or not), but if I were to only sum a number once, how would I go about excluding them if they are already divisible?

Answer (score 0):

Your current code basically does:

- Go over all those numbers that should be divisible, so 5, 10 and 12.

  - Go over all numbers till number
  - If the number is divisible, add it to the result.
  - return the sum (which is too early, as the outer loop hasn't finished yet)

Now if you take 60 for example, then that will both be divisible by 5, 10 and 12 so it will be added three times.

You should invert your loops:

```
  let result = 0;

  outer: for(let n = 1; n <= number; n++) {
    for(let divider of [5, 10, 12]) {
      if(n % divider !== 0) continue outer;
    }
    result += n;
 }

 return result;
```

---

But that is quite inefficient. Instead you could take the biggest number, 12 in this case, and check all of its multiples against the other numbers (12, 24, ...).

```
  let result = 0;
  const dividers = [5, 10, 12];
  const biggest = dividers.pop();

  for(let n = biggest; n < number; n += biggest) {
    if(dividers.every(divider => n % divider === 0))
      result += n;
  }
```

Comment: So I reversed the for statements, but it still results in 0. The way I had originally thought of it, I would run each item from the array individually through all numbers, then sum those numbers before moving on to the next item in the array. I didn't realize this until Huangism mentioned it above, but I would also think that if one number was divisible by an item in the array, that it wouldn't be added to the sum if it was divisible by a different item in the array. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out! I was missing [x] in the if statement to signify the individual item from the array would act as the modulus (if that's what it is called). The resulting code looks like this:

```
function sumOfMultiples(number) {
    let numb = [5, 10, 12];
    let sum = 0;
    for (let x=0; x<=numb.length; x++){
        for (let i=0; i<number; i++) {
            if(i % numb[x] === 0){
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;        
}
```

It does count a number twice if it is divisible by multiple array items, but I will work through that.

Anyway, thank you all for the help!